# Query values from a C# Generic Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Here's the code i have:

```
Dictionary<double, long> dictionary = new Dictionary<double, long>();
dictionary.Add(99, 500);
dictionary.Add(98, 500);
dictionary.Add(101, 8000);
dictionary.Add(103, 6000);
dictionary.Add(104, 5);
dictionary.Add(105, 2000);

double price = 100;
```

the query i want is:
the key that is nearest price AND with the lowest value.
so in the above example it should return 99.
how do i code this in LINQ ? 
i have seen alot of linq examples but i cannt adapt any of them to my needs b/c my query has 2 conditions.

thanks for any help.

edit:
based on comments from @nintendojunkie and @DmitryMartovoi i have had to rethink my approach.
if i prioritize key closest to price then resulting value may not be the lowest and if i prioritize value first then the key may be too far from price so the query will have to prioritize BOTH the key and value the same and give me the lowest value with the closest key to price. both key and value are equally important.
can anyone help on this?
thanks

Comment: Nearest ? Near from what ?

Comment: @Sharped the value of price variable

Comment: What if one key has the "nearest price", but a different key has the "lowest value"?  If your conditions are on two independent factors, you either need to prioritize one over the other (e.g. nearest price, and if two are the same, then the lowest value) or come up with a hybrid condition (e.g. each 1 unit of price is worth n units of value).

Comment: @nintendojunkie .. not sure why the priority matters .. this would be a AND statement .. the key closest to price AND the lowest value.. in the case above the only one that returns true would be 99, 500

Comment: @user3498520: why not 101, 8000? the dictionary has unique keys, so if you got "the nearest" key, you got the single value for it.

Comment: @user3498520 In your example above, the one with the nearest price would be either (99, 500) or (101, 8000), but the one with the lowest value is (104, 5).  There is no single key that has the nearest price AND the lowest value.  Which is more important?

Comment: @nintendojunkie ....i stand corrected you are both right .. noob mistake. i will edit my question

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi you are correct

Comment: @user3498520 With your edit, you're going to have to come up with a way to quantify "importance" of the two conditions.  If you have a choice between an option close to the price and an option further from the price, how much better value does the further price have to be before you would consider it?  Essentially you're creating a new "fitness" variable that is calculated from the price and value and then picking the one with the best fit.

Comment: @nintendojunkie you are absolutely correct !!! to put it another way the further away a key is from price, the less important it is to me. so therefore i dont care about its value. i would need to continue the search till i can find the key closest to price with the lowest value. but when i prioritize the key i end up with the wrong pair... so i think you nailed it in terms of what i need.. but how would you suggest going about it .. in a for loop ? ....thanks very much

Comment: @user3498520 You can still do this with LINQ - Douglas' answer is a good example.  He calculates the "fitness" as the price difference plus the value - each 1 additional price point is worth sacrificing one point of value.  If 1 price point should be worth, say, 5 points of value, then you'll want to multiply the price difference by 5 to weight them appropriately.  Basically you need to come up with an "exchange rate" between price and value.

Comment: @nintendojunkie your insight is greatly appreciated. i dont have enough credit to +1 your code. but thanks

Comment: @user3498520 Even though you can't +1, you can still select a "best" answer.  Pick whichever one you felt was most helpful for you and will be most helpful for those reading your question in the future.  Or if you come up with something yourself, you can create your own answer and select that as the best answer.

Comment: @nintendojunkie ok i didnt know that ..you were very helpful in bringing alot of the intricacies of the dic search to light for me .. i have marked your answer as best. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works if you change your dictionary key's data type to `decimal` instead of `double`.

```
decimal price = 100;
decimal smallestDiff = dictionary.Keys.Min(n => Math.Abs(n - price));
var nearest = dictionary.Where(n => Math.Abs(n.Key - price) == smallestDiff)
                        .OrderBy(n => n.Value).First();
```

If you use `double` this may fail due to rounding issues, but `decimal` is preferred for anything having to do with money to avoid those issues.

Comment: please see my edit i need same priority for both key and value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
var result = dictionary.Select(c => new { c.Key, Diff = Math.Abs(price - c.Key) + Math.Abs(price - c.Value), c.Value }).OrderBy(c => c.Diff).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nakeruri ...thanks for your response .... i need the key NEAREST price not just less than price.

Comment: thank you for your update .. based on the comments from others i now know that i have to come up with a rating system as to the importance of each key vs value pair. therefore, i have to rethink my algorithm for searching the dic. your approach was one of the best but unfortunately i cannt mark 2 answers as the best. but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget - you use dictionary. Dictionary has only unique keys. I think you consider this structure as `List<KeyValuePair<double, long>>`. If so - please look to this example:

```
var minimumKeyDifference = dictionary.Min(y => Math.Abs(y.Key - price));
var minimumItems = dictionary.Where(x => Math.Abs(x.Key - price).Equals(minimumKeyDifference));
var desiredKey = dictionary.First(x => x.Value.Equals(minimumItems.Where(y =>  y.Key.Equals(x.Key)).Min(y => y.Value))).Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that you need to find the closest price *and* the lowest value, but you don't define the rules for attributing precedence between two. In the below, I'm attributing them equal precedence: a price distance of 1 is equivalent to a value of 1.

```
var closest = 
    dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => Math.Abs(kvp.Key - price) + kvp.Value).First();
```

The `OrderBy(…).First()` should be replaced by a `MinBy(…)` operator, if available, for performance.

**Edit**: If the value is only meant to serve as a tiebreaker, then use this (also posted by [Giorgi Nakeuri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28615342/1149773)):

```
var closest = 
    dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => Math.Abs(kvp.Key - price))
              .ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
              .First();
```

Comment: thanks for the code.  please see the edit to my original question .. if i give precedence to one over the other the result will not be correct ..

Comment: @user3498520: Yes, that's why my answer gives them equal precedence.

Comment: i tested your code and with the above example it returned 104 .. which means that your code is prioritizing value over key. the key im looking for is 99

Comment: The key of 99 gives you a value of 500. The key of 104 gives you a value of 5. Thus, although your key is slightly better (by 3), my value is much better (by 495).

Comment: your insight is much appreciated. but for my purposes the farther the value is from price the less important it becomes ... so how would you suggest i rework your code to give more importance to key being near price after it has already found one far away. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
var price = 100.0;

var nearestKey = (from pair in dictionary
                 let diff = Math.Abs(pair.Key - price)
                 select new {Key = pair.Key, Diff = diff}
                 order by diff desc).First().Key;
var minValue = dictionary[nearestKey];
```

Comment: depending of what you mean under the "nearest" ofc.

Comment: nearest and lower so if he has '95' and '101' compared to a price  of 100 it should pick 95

Comment: Actually the second query is nonsense... There can not be several entries in dictionary by key

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: yep, fixed)

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi thanks for the code ... please see my edit .. here you are prioritizing the key nearest price .. as i stated in my edit this would give me the wrong result. i would need same priority for both the key and value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a magic linq query but i suggest to try the in below.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static double? GetNearestValue (this IDictionary<double, long> dictionary, double value)
    {
        if (dictionary == null || dictionary.Count == 0)
            return null;

        double? nearestDiffValue = null;
        double? nearestValue = null;

        foreach (var item in dictionary) {
            double currentDiff = Math.Abs (item.Key - value);
            if (nearestDiffValue == null || currentDiff < nearestDiffValue.Value) {
                nearestDiffValue = currentDiff;
                nearestValue = item.Value;
            }
        }

        return nearestValue;
    }
}
```

And call like this

```
Console.WriteLine (dictionary.GetNearestValue (100d));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var min = dictionary
            .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value)
            .Select(pair =>
                new
                {
                    k = pair.Key,
                    d = Math.Abs(pair.Key - price)
                })
            .OrderBy(t => t.d)
            .Select(t => t.k)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```